# Are there any specific tactics or strategies I should use to improve my score at Fruit Ninja?

Tags: fruit-ninja

Obviously, I can just "miss fewer fruit" and "avoid more bombs".

But when I compare my score to the high scores, I suspect there's a specific approach more specifc than "go study with fruit monks in Tibet".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure you are using sound.  The bombs will make a sound before they are launched which helps some.
2. Don't be afraid to use the pause button.  Once you pause/unpause, you can't pause again for a second or two, but it can be useful when all hell breaks loose.
3. Remember that for every 100 fruit, an X will disappear  (i.e. when your score crosses 100,200,300,etc).

Comment: Any particular way to get critical hits or is it just random?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using sound, the pause button, and trying to regain lives, you could always turn your device upside down. Doing so will have the bottom free of your fingers and the fruit will come up to you. This just keeps the field open so you can get more fruit and miss bombs from the increased vision you have over the screen.

This is just a tactic I learned awhile back.

Off-topic: I know this question is over a year old but I believe that my suggestion will be relevant to any person who seeks the answer to this question anytime in the near future.

Answer (score 4):

As often as you can, try and slice 3 or more fruit in a single slice. Doing so gives you double points for those fruit.

Answer (score 2):

In arcade mode:

- use all 4 fingers to do the crazy rapid slice on the final bonus pomegranate. You can improve your bonus from low 20s to high 50s, perhaps even 60+ with practice (I managed to cross 60 just twice).
- if you accidentally hit a bomb (-10), and you haven't had an otherwise fantastic game, then deliberately hit 2 more bombs. This will fetch you the "Bomb lover" bonus which is worth +50, netting you +20 after subtracting the bomb negatives.